# Проблема с name is not defined

Tags: python, python-3.x, variable

Переменная voprros:

```
voprros = print ("Сколько лет вы занимайтесь программированием?: ")
```

Код:

```
priv = input ("Здравствуйте. Вы попали в опрос. Напишите 'Да' если хотите продолжить, нет чтобы остановить: ")
if priv == "Да":
    print (voprros)
elif priv == "да":
    print (voprros)
elif priv == "Нет":
    raise SystemExit
elif priv == "нет":
    raise SystemExit
elif priv == "no":
    raise SystemExit
elif priv == "net":
    raise SystemExit
```

Сама ошибка:

```
Здравствуйте. Вы попали в опрос. Напишите 'Да' если хотите продолжить, нет чтобы остановить: Да
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\lala.py", line 10, in <module>
    print (voprros)
NameError: name 'voprros' is not defined
```

Весь код:

```
from colorama import Fore, Back, Style
from colorama import init
import time
init ()

#Body
priv = input ("Здравствуйте. Вы попали в опрос. Напишите 'Да' если хотите продолжить, нет чтобы остановить: ")
if priv == "Да":
    print (voprros)
elif priv == "да":
    print (voprros)
elif priv == "Нет":
    raise SystemExit
elif priv == "нет":
    raise SystemExit
elif priv == "no":
    raise SystemExit
elif priv == "net":
    raise SystemExit

    

#Вопросы:
print (Fore.RED)
voprros = print ("Сколько лет вы занимайтесь программированием?")
time.sleep (2)
otvv = input ("Пишите ответ сюда: ")
```

Comment: Значит в той области видимости той переменной не видно, приложите весь код

Comment: Я вот только не знаю как

Comment: Под вопросом есть [edit], тыкаете на нее и добавляете все содержимое из `lala.py` :)

Comment: Всё, добавил. 111

Comment: У вас переменная `voprros` создается уже после того как к ней обращаетесь. Переместите блок с нею под условие с да

Comment: Понял, спасибо :)

Answer (score 1):

У вас переменная `voprros` создается уже после того как к ней обращаетесь. Плюс, там опечатка в `voprros` помещаете результат `print`, а не `input`, поэтому там всегда будет `None`, т.к. `print` только его и возвращает

Немного подправил код:

```py
import time
import sys

from colorama import Fore, init
init()

# Body
priv = input("Здравствуйте. Вы попали в опрос. Напишите 'Да' если хотите продолжить, нет чтобы остановить: ")
priv = priv.lower()
if priv == "да":
    print(Fore.RED)
    print("Сколько лет вы занимайтесь программированием?")
    time.sleep(2)
    otvv = input("Пишите ответ сюда: ")

elif priv in ["нет", "no", "net"]:
    sys.exit()
```

Comment: Там скорее просто нужно вывести `print("Сколько лет вы занимайтесь программированием?")`, а потом ответ вписывается в `input("Пишите ответ сюда: ")`

Comment: @insolor, похоже на то, поменял :)